# Converting map into tuple

Tags: apache-pig

I am loading hbase table using pig.

```
product = LOAD 'hbase://product' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('a:*', '-loadKey true') AS (id:bytearray, a:map[])
```

The relation `product` has a tuple that has map in it. I want to convert the map data into tuple
Here is the sample..

```
grunt>dump product;
06:177602927,[cloud_service#true,wvilnk#true,cmpgeo#true,cmplnk#true,webvid_standard#true,criteria_search#true,typeahead_search#true,aasgbr#true,lnkmin#false,aasdel#true,aasmcu#true,aasvia#true,lnkalt#false,aastlp#true,cmpeel#true,aasfsc#true,aasser#true,aasdhq#true,aasgbm#true,gboint#true,lnkupd#true,aasbig#true,webvid_basic#true,cmpelk#true]
06:177927527,[cloud_service#true,wvilnk#true,cmpgeo#true,cmplnk#true,webvid_standard#true,criteria_search#true,typeahead_search#true,aasgbr#false,lnkmin#false,aasdel#false,aasmcu#false,aasvia#false,lnkalt#false,aastlp#true,cmpeel#true,aasfsc#false,aasser#false,aasdhq#true,aasgbm#false,gboint#true,lnkupd#true,aasbig#false,webvid_basic#true,cmpelk#true,blake#true]
```

I want to convert each tuple into individual records like below

```
177602927,cloud_service,true
177602927,wvilnk,true
177602927,cmpgeo,true
177602927,cmpgeo,true
```

I am pretty new to pig and perhaps this is my first time to do something with Pig Latin. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a fix for my problem.

I used a UDF called `MapEntriesToBag` which will convert all the maps into bags.
Here is my code.

```
>register /your/path/to/this/Jar/Pigitos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>DEFINE MapEntriesToBag pl.ceon.research.pigitos.pig.udf.MapEntriesToBag();
>product = LOAD 'hbase://product' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('a:*', '-loadKey true') AS (id:bytearray, a:map[])
>b = foreach product generate flatten(SUBSTRING($0,3,12)), flatten(MapEntriesToBag($1));
```

The UDF is available in the Jar Pigitos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. You can download this jar from [here](https://github.com/kawaa/Pigitos/raw/master/Pigitos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)

For more information you can refer to this [link](http://hakunamapdata.com/pigitos-in-action-reading-hbase-column-family-content-in-a-real-world-application/). It has more interesting UDF's related to Map datatype.